# terminar un ciclo while el cual esta ingresando valores de texto en una lista

Tags: python, lista, bucles, while

Usando un `while` debo llenar una lista hasta que no se ponga ningún dato y presionando *enter* termine el `while` guardando lo de la lista.
Esto es lo que tengo no se como hacerlo estoy aprendiendo.

```
empleados= []

while (que debería poner aquí para acabar el ciclo al no ingresar ningun dato nuevo cuando precione enter)
   empleado_nuevo =input("empleado nuevo: ")
   empleados.append(empleado_nuevo)
```

Comment: No sé python pero supongo que debe existir un `break`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para romper el ciclo puedes poner un `break` y evaluar la entrada del usuario

```py
empleados = []
#nunca parara a menos que le indiquemos
while True:
   empleado_nuevo =input("empleado nuevo: ")
   #verificamos si dio enter
   if empleado_nuevo == "":
        empleados = ",".join(empleados)
        print(f"los empleados son: {empleados}") #mostramos los empleados
        break #salimos del ciclo
   empleados.append(empleado_nuevo)
```

esto funciona si das enter ya que la condicion evalua esto `""` y cuando das enter no se digita ningun caracter por lo que la condicion se cumple, mas no se cumplira cuando pongas un espacio y luego el enter, ya que sera `" "` (con un espacio)

Answer (score 2):

```
empleados= []

while True:
    empleado_nuevo =input("empleado nuevo: ")
    if (empleado_nuevo == "" ):
        break
    empleados.append(empleado_nuevo)
print(empleados)
```

En el caso de Python no tenemos el bucle `do-while` por lo que se lo puede simular haciendo que el bucle siempre sea verdadero por lo que continuara infinitamente, pero al momento de evaluar un espacio hacemos que el código pare con un `break`, el `empleado.append()` va después del condicional ya que si lo ponemos antes incluirá el empleado vacío dentro de la lista y al final imprimimos la lista de empleados.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás utilizando `Python 3.8` en adelante, puedes utilizar el operador morsa:

```
empleados= []

while (empleado_nuevo := input("empleado nuevo: ")) != '':
   empleados.append(empleado_nuevo)
```